# About the input format of vowpal_wabbit

Tags: machine-learning, classification, vowpalwabbit

I am new in this aspect.
I want to train with a series of data and predict. I have tried to long time, could you tell me what's the wrong with me?

My train data looks like this (I pick top several lines here):

```
-1 '13731#276 |f gender:0 age_range:2 action0:1 action1:0 action2:1 action3:0
-1 '70175#4214 |f gender:0 age_range:4 action0:0 action1:0 action2:1 action3:0
-1 '89370#2598 |f gender:1 age_range:2 action0:8 action1:0 action2:1 action3:0
1 '89371#1250 |f gender:0 age_range:2 action0:0 action1:0 action2:1 action3:0
-1 '89372#2792 |f gender:1 age_range:5 action0:0 action1:0 action2:1 action3:0
1 '89372#962 |f gender:1 age_range:5 action0:0 action1:0 action2:1 action3:0
-1 '89373#4472 |f gender:0 age_range:7 action0:5 action1:0 action2:1 action3:0
```

test data like this:

```
1 '177796#1807 |f gender:0 age_range:5 action0:5 action1:0 action2:1 action3:0
1 '155638#2445 |f gender:0 age_range:7 action0:3 action1:0 action2:1 action3:0
1 '155639#658 |f gender:1 age_range:2 action0:5 action1:0 action2:1 action3:0
1 '127479#2480 |f gender:0 age_range:7 action0:0 action1:0 action2:1 action3:0
1 '127478#1245 |f gender:0 age_range:4 action0:1 action1:0 action2:1 action3:0
1 '127473#4995 |f gender:1 age_range:4 action0:13 action1:0 action2:1 action3:0
1 '127472#45 |f gender:0 age_range:7 action0:4 action1:0 action2:1 action3:0
```

yes, they looks no different. I don't know if it is right. I see many people on github write them in this way.

and my vw command is as follow:

```
vw -d train.vw --loss_function=logistic -f model.vw
vw -d test.vw -t -i model.vw --loss_function=logistic -r shop.preds.txt
```

Well, the result is

```
-2.816693 177796#1807
-2.817430 155638#2445
-2.981194 155639#658
-2.821442 127479#2480
-2.823012 127478#1245
-2.968556 127473#4995
-2.816092 127472#45
-2.820939 127471#4010
-2.975476 127470#593
-2.820105 155634#4103
-2.799539 155635#2980
-3.139279 127475#1469
```

I don't know why is that, the number become less than -2, in fact my ideal result is like:

```
202178#1665,0.67
156148#4730,0.50
132360#2459,0.24
132360#144,0.99
180387#1534,0.48
187963#1360,0.19
158187#2534,0.54
188206#4890,0.70
```

At least I want the number to be correct, but it is all 1.
Could you tell me how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to predict probabilities, then instead of `vw -d test.vw -t -i model.vw --loss_function=logistic -r shop.preds.txt` you should use

`vw -d test.vw -t -i model.vw  --loss_function=logistic --link=logistic -p shop.preds.txt`

If you want to get the most probable label (-1 or +1), use

`vw -d test.vw -t -i model.vw  --loss_function=logistic --binary -p shop.preds.txt`

See https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Predicting-probabilities

Comment: And to convert from vw raw prediction format to your preferred CSV format you may use:  `perl -lane 'print $F[1], ",", $F[0]' shop.preds.txt`